# What's the best way to hack on Gem dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm working on a Rails 3.2 app, and I've fixed a few bugs that I've encountered in the [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail). To workaround the bug while I wait for the pull request to go through, I get included in a new gem, etc etc, I've added my own to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'mail', :git => 'git://github.com/tonyarkles/mail.git'
```

Unfortunately, it looks like Rails has a hard dependency on the 2.4 series of mail:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mail":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.11) ruby depends on
      mail (~> 2.4.4) ruby

    mail (2.6.0.edge)
```

What's the best way to work around this? Also for rails the 3.2.x branch, changed the dependency there, and runs both Rails and mail off my own versions correct? It seems like there should be a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back-port your fixes to the latest 2.4.x branch, and add your copy of that to your Gemfile.

Once your fixes have been accepted on master, submit another pull request for the same fixes on the 2.4.x branch.

Comment: No need to feel like an idiot. It's not obvious until it's obvious.

Comment: You can also `gem unpack` and tell the gemfile to use the :path, then edit the lib/version.rb file.